# Mysql_pconnect alternative in order to work

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-pconnect

So I know that mysql_pconnect is deprecated, is there a way actually to make this work, I have an old script which in the connection file has the following:

```
$success = mysql_pconnect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
if (!$success)
    die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.</b>");
$success = mysql_select_db ($database);
if (!$success) {
    print "<b>Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct.";
    die();
}
```

Do I have an alternative to this?

//LE

```
try {
    $success = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.</b>");
}

$success = mysql_select_db ($database);
if (!$success) {
    print "<b>Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct.";
    die();
}
```

this gives me "Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli` however `PDO` is recommended for doing queries and plain php nowadays.

```
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db;
$r = $connect->query('SELECT ...');
$rows = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: I can't use $connect, this is an old script with a tone of queries, i have to adapt this somehow to work

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [mysql_pconnect docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php):

**Warning**
   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
related FAQ for more information.

**Alternatives to this function include:

[mysqli_connect() with *p:* host prefix](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) with `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` as a driver option**

Answer (score -1):

The mysql_pconnect function creates a persistent connection to the database. To do that with PDO (the recommended way to access a database in PHP), you can do this:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.</b>");
}
```

Note that when you use PDO you don't need call mysql_select_db (which is also deprecated). With PDO, the database is part of the DSN (the first parameter of the PDO constructor). In fact, you'll need to replace every call to a mysql_* function with the equivalent PDO method.